# Error while using Makemigrations in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am totally new to django so any help would be appreciate
I wrote the following code and in my terminal I used python manage.py makemigrations and got error

**django Model**

```
class ctrybe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Error in terminal**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/src/ctrybe/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class ctrybe(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/src/ctrybe/models.py", line 8, in ctrybe
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=120)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

I use python 3.4

Comment: remove `max_length=120` from `__unicode__` and run again :) Also replace `__unicode__` with `__str__` since you're using python 3.4 which is also not good. You should use python 3.6 or at least 3.5 :)

Comment: still got the error

Comment: Why do you use `__unicode__`? This is a Python-2.x feature.

Comment: i used __str__ also and got error

Comment: updated. I removed max_length=120 from the unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typo. It should be `max_length`, not `max_lenght`.